# kpathsea/fontspec does not recognize a font whose name has a space in it

Tags: fonts, xetex, fontspec

Using XeLaTeX and the fontspec package, I am experiencing problems using fonts whose name includes the space character. Here is a simple example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\begin{document}\end{document}
```

gives, upon `xelatex` the error:

```
kpathsea: Invalid fontname `Times New Roman', contains ' '
```

I have used this font before and previously working examples ceased to work when I re-installed my operating system (Ubuntu 11.04) and TeXlive2011.

Comment: This error usually arises when `fontspec` fails to find the font at all. Are you sure that the font is available still on your system? (Can you use it a regular application like Open Office?)

Comment: The font is indeed missing on OpenOffice. The error message is quite misleading.

Comment: On my system, `fontspec` gives a very helpful error right after the error you mention. Maybe you're not seeing the whole thing.  It clearly says `fontspec error: "font-not-found"` (etc.)

Comment: I've turned my comments into an answer.

Comment: @Marc: It is a good advice to avoid **file** names with spaces, but the problem here is about a **font** name. This font name is simply a string stored in the font and XeTeX can/should handle such names without problem.

Comment: @Ulrike Thanks for pointing that out. I missed that. I'll remove my comment and will remove this one tomorrow.

Comment: I got this error on OS X. I had installed latex with Homebrew and matplotlib with pip. latex could't find the fonts, so I located the fonts that ship with matplotlib (it was twenty-something) and opened and imported them with Font Book.
And the error was gone.

Comment: @AlanMunn, yes, but what it is confusing is that in the error message the name of the font doesn't have the space. (At least in my system TeXLive2014/Linux)

Comment: @alfC Right but the actual `fontspec` error message makes no mention of spaces: it says simply "font not found".

Comment: @AlanMunn, yes, for example, I know for sure that Arial and Times New Roman are installed, but Arial works and Times New Roman doesn't. The only difference I can find is the space in the name. Granted, I am talking about Linux, not Windows, and that can be part of the problem.

Comment: @alfC Sometimes fonts in linux don't get registered and you need to load them using the filename.  See [Figuring out Xetex fonts under Debian](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/183241) perhaps?

Comment: what bothers me most is not having to use filenames but also having to specify the full path. Maybe I can just copy the font files into some magic directory in `texmf`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The error you are seeing usually arises when `fontspec` can't find the font at all. It is usually accompanied  by the following more helpful error generated by `fontspec` itself:

```
kpathsea: Invalid fontname `A Funny Font', contains ' '


!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!
./kpathsea-test.tex:4: fontspec error: "font-not-found"
! 
! The font "A Funny Font" cannot be found.
! 
! See the fontspec documentation for further information.
! 
! For immediate help type H <return>.
!...............................................  

l.4 \setmainfont{A Funny Font}
```

Maybe your editing environment is hiding some of the console output from you.

Any font that is usable on your system in a regular application (e.g. Open Office) should be found by `fontspec`.  So you should check to see if "Times New Roman" is actually available on your system after your OS update.