# space in font name

Tags: fonts, xetex

This is related to [Fonts for PolyTonic Greek](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/127222/fonts-for-polytonic-greek). That post contains (supposedly) working example using the names of many fonts, and each font name contains a space. Names include: "CMU Serif", "EB Garamond", "GFS Artemisia". 
The post states that the fonts are all part of TeXLive 2013. I have a TeXLive updated 2013 distribution. I copied the code exactly and attempted to xelatex it. But it returned an error stating that a font cannot have a space in its name. How did the previous poster manage to run code in which all font names contain spaces?

Comment: For system installed fonts, `fontspec` uses the name of the font as it would appear, e.g. in a regular application on your machine.  This will typically include spaces.  If you are requesting a font by filename, (which you must with XeTeX with fonts in your `texmf` directories) it cannot contain spaces.

Comment: What OS are you using? On GNU/Linux, fonts in the `texmf` directories are typically also made system fonts. At least, a lot of Linux distros do this if you install using their packages, and it is very easy to do this yourself if you use upstream's installer. I don't know, however, whether this works on Mac OS X or Windows. Perhaps that is what @AlanMunn is thinking of?

Comment: You are probably simply getting the "font not found error". http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43029/kpathsea-fontspec-does-not-recognize-a-font-whose-name-has-a-space-in-it. The example works fine for me in TL2014 (on windows), but with TL2013 I get errors due to missing fonts too.